# ASP.NET Core Identity JWT always unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm following FullStack Mark's guide to setup an aspnet core with identity and angular, the problem is that i'm not getting the authorization part to work, i always get an 401 unauthorized, registering is working, and logging in is working too, i think that the problem may be in the generated token (it says invalid signature in jwt.io validation)

sorry if the question is poorly formulated, first time asking.

FullStack Mark's guide that i'm following: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

my entire application code : https://github.com/GiovaniHarada/AngularConce/tree/master/Conce

Login Controller

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CredentialsResource credentials)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
        if (identity == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
        }

        var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, _jwtFactory, credentials.UserName, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
        return new OkObjectResult(jwt);
    }
```

Get Claims Identity

```
    private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentity(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);

        // get the user to verifty
        var userToVerify = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (userToVerify == null) return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);

        // check the credentials
        if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password))
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(userName, userToVerify.Id));
        }

        // Credentials are invalid, or account doesn't exist
        return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
    }
```

Generate Encoded Token function

```
    public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var claims = new[]
     {
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
             identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
             identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id)
         };

        // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
            signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return encodedJwt;
    }
```

Comment: did you plug in your token "secret" in jwt.io? jwt.io will say the signature is invalid if your dont add your secret to it

Comment: also, i dont see where your "GenerateEncodedToken" function is being called from.

Comment: @victor what did you mean by plug in my token ?

Comment: After you copy and paste your jwt token into jwt.io homepage, you also have to provide it with the secret you used to create the token, otherwise it will say "Signature invalid" because from its point of view it cant  validate your token without knowing the secret.

Comment: i'm using GenerateEncodedToken inside GenerateJwt

Comment: ok, the token now says signature verified, thanks for the tip, as you can see, i know almost nothing about JwT and identity or oauth

Comment: jwts are pretty simple and straightforward. Its worthwhile to read up on them so you understand how they work and how they do what they do.

Comment: i will try read about it, thanks :)